# wpf datepicker start from year in calendar

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datepicker

I have [standart datepicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), mvvm.

```
<Custom:DatePicker>
     <Custom:DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Custom:Calendar" >                                       
                <Setter Property="DisplayMode"  Value="Year"/>                      
            </Style>                        
     </Custom:DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
</Custom:DatePicker>
```

But it does not works. I should have code in xaml and DatePicker control, not Calendar+TextBlock.

Comment: start from year in calendar ? you mean the display format?

Comment: DisplayMode of calendar (in calendar date selection area), not datepicker PART_TextBox text

Comment: could share more about `Custom:DatePicker`? perhaps share a link if any.

Comment: this is the standart control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `DatePicker` control `changes` the value of `DisplayMode` of the `Calendar` to `Month` before opening the popup, so your value in style become useless.

I have solved the problem with the help of attached properties

below code applies to a standard `DatePicker` control

```
<DatePicker xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Calendar"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Calendar}}">
            <Setter Property="l:CalendarHelper.DisplayMode"
                    Value="Year" />
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
</DatePicker>
```

I have created an attached property `CalendarHelper.DisplayMode` and set the desired value in style.

CalendarHelper class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class CalendarHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static CalendarMode GetDisplayMode(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (CalendarMode)obj.GetValue(DisplayModeProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDisplayMode(DependencyObject obj, CalendarMode value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DisplayModeProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMode.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayModeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMode", typeof(CalendarMode), typeof(CalendarHelper), new PropertyMetadata(CalendarMode.Month, OnModeChanged));

        private static void OnModeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Calendar cal = d as Calendar;
            cal.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged += (ss, ee) => cal.SetValue(Calendar.DisplayModeProperty, e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

in the class above I am listening to `IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged` event of calendar and setting the desired property value in the handler. this event occurs after popup is opened hence will retain the desired mode.

Comment: @KyloRen answer was tested before posting, you may perhaps create a new question with some sample code you may have wrote.

Comment: Will other datepicker styles interfere with this? And if I can get this to work I was going to upvote your answer, since no-one else has.